# Make output of *apply look pretty

Tags: r, knitr

I have the following line

```
apply(wrld_simpl@data, 1, FUN=function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

which gives the following output

```
 ATG DZA AZE ALB ARM AGO ASM ARG AUS BHR BRB BMU BHS BGD BLZ BIH BOL MMR 
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
BEN SLB BRA BGR BRN CAN KHM LKA COG COD BDI CHN AFG BTN CHL CYM CMR TCD 
 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

and so on. I know that counting the NA's for this data set doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but once I merged this data with a 'home grown' data set it it more meaningful and my challenge remains the same. The latter two questions arise as I want to put this into a report for which I use knitr:

1. Can I produce this output in a cross table for all variables, meaning the countries in the left column and some variables (e.g. wrld_simpl@data[6:11]) as headers?
2. How to exchange the country code with the country name (wrld_simpl@data$NAME) as not every reader knows the codes well?
3. How can I put the output into a pretty table (borders, headers, label)?

Any pointers are appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Concerning question three: What exactly do you mean by "pretty table"? Do you want see the table printed, as pdf, html? You could check out the xtable package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html which works pretty smooth with knitr.

Comment: That was a good hint as it was what I meant. After some work I got my tables into the pdf. Now I need to find out how to show all results. As there are 246 countries, the results don't show on one page, but get cut off with no results on the next page. There is always more to learn (esp. for a newbie like me!) But many thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the `plyr` package for such a kind of things, since the **ply-functions are way more consistent to use than the default *apply methods of `r-base`.

```
library("plyr")
library("maptools")
data( wrld_simpl )
adply( wrld_simpl@data, 1, function(x) {
  sum(is.na( x[ c("LON", "LAT") ] )) # change to the columns you want to count the NA's on
})[ ,5:12 ]
```

Comment: Great. Any pointers, how to add a long list of variables to the count? In particular variables 14 to 61 of my data set. Thanks again!

Comment: How about you just replace the `[ ,5:12 ]` with something appropriate, e.g. `[, c(5:12,14:61) ]` ?

Comment: Geez! Now I got it! Thanks! So the final line looks like this: `head(adply( wrld_simpl2@data, 1, function(x) {sum(is.na( x[ , c(14:61) ] )) })) [,c(5,62)]` (Note that this is wrld_simpl2.) Can anybody help on my question 3?